# CakePHP error.log does not show url

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am looking at the error.log file for my site and I am seeing a few errors.

It tells me the file and the line number which helps, but it would be a lot easier to figure out what was going on if I knew what URL was requested that caused the problem.

Anyways to tell the logs to log the URL requested when they log an error?

Comment: not out of the box - I had to hack the 1.3 core to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Cake has support for [customising your logging](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1582/Creating-and-configuring-log-streams). You probably want to override `write` to prepend the URL for the request before letting `parent::write()` do all the hard work.